# I know my pravara and veda, can I find out my veda shakha and sutra?

Tags: rig-veda, brahmins, gotra, telugu, sutra

I am Rigvediya "karnakamma" telugu brahmin of kamakayana visvamitra gotra, pravara being vaisvamitra daivasravasa daivatarasa. From this information could I find out my veda shakha and kalpasutra?

Comment: According to me,  pravara and gotra don't give away necessarily one's śākhā, they just give info about one's family line and ancestry.  People from a different gotra and pravara can be a part of the same śākhā. And people from the same gotra and pravara can be part of different śākhās